# Is there a way to take a code which is defined inside render , out from render function in React?

Tags: reactjs, render

I have coded a function inside render function. When I call it in the return it works. But now what I want to do is get it out and place it before render. Is there a way to do it like that? I have given the function below.In here what I have commented is the final output what I want to get

```
import React from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Form, FormGroup, Input, Label } from 'reactstrap';

import * as Icon from 'react-bootstrap-icons';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

import ActionButton from '../../components/ActionButton/ActionButton';
import InputFieldWithImage from '../../components/InputFieldWithImage/InputFieldWithImage';
import SelectedFilesDisplayLabel from '../../components/SelectedFilesDisplayLabel/SelectedFilesDisplayLabel';
import DropDown from '../../components/DropDown/DropDown';
import CustomToolbar from '../../components/EditorToolbar/EditorToolbar';

import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
import './Popup.scss';

import Amy from './../../assets/images/Amy.png';

const icons = ReactQuill.Quill.import('ui/icons');
icons['link'] = <Icon.Link />;

class AddTicket extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedFile: null,
      title: '',
      description: '',
      assignee: '',
      employer: '',
      type: 'A',
      priority: 'Top',
      edit: '',
      text: '',
      editorHtml: '',
      uploadedFileName: '',
      uploadedFileType: '',
      flagPdf: false,
      flagImage: false,
      flagDoc: false,
      selectedFiles: [],
      dropdownOpen: false,
      isOpen: false,
      typeArray: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
      priorityArray: ['Top', 'Middle', 'Least', 'No']
    };
  }

  // This is the function for file upload.Here it checks whether there is the same file already attached
  // and if not stored in selectedFiles array.Flag is used here in the function to keep the state of the file
  // whether there contain a file with same name.
  handleChangeFile = (event) => {
    let fileExists;
    let temp = [];
    let files = [];
    let tempSelectedFilesArr = this.state.selectedFiles;

    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      let file = event.target.files[i];
      if (
        file.type === 'application/pdf' ||
        file.type === 'image/png' ||
        file.type === 'image/jpeg' ||
        file.type === 'application/msword' ||
        file.type ===
          'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' ||
        file.type === 'video/mp4'
      ) {
        files.push(file);
      }
    }

    if (tempSelectedFilesArr.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fileExists = 0;
        for (let j = 0; j < tempSelectedFilesArr.length; j++) {
          if (files[i].name === tempSelectedFilesArr[j].name) {
            fileExists = 1;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (fileExists === 0) {
          temp.push(files[i]);
        }
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        temp.push(files[i]);
      }
    }

    this.setState({
      selectedFiles: tempSelectedFilesArr.concat(temp)
    });
  };

  // This handles text which input to title,assignee and employee
  handleChangeInputs = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  // In this function, text which are input into the descripion box ,are stored in the state
  handleDescription = (html) => {
    this.setState({ editorHtml: html });
  };

  // These two function handleType,handlePriority  are send as props to the dropdown component.
  handleType = (e) => {
    this.setState({ type: e.currentTarget.textContent });
  };

  handlePriority = (e) => {
    this.setState({ priority: e.currentTarget.textContent });
  };

  // This function handle all the input values. Values are send to the backend from this
  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.title);

    console.log(this.state.type);

    console.log(this.state.priority);

    console.log(this.state.assignee);

    console.log(this.state.employer);
    this.props.handleClose();
  };

  // Uploaded files are displayed in the screen. After clicking the close button,
  // this function calls
  cardClose(value) {
    let temp = this.state.selectedFiles.filter((n) => {
      return n.name !== value;
    });
    this.setState({
      selectedFiles: temp
    });
  }

  // These are used in the react quill component.
  static modules = {
    toolbar: {
      container: '#toolbar'
    }
  };


  // decription = this.state.selectedFiles.map((item, key) => {
  //   let size = item.size / 1048576;
  //   size = size.toFixed(2);
  //   const K = item.name;
  //   return (
  //     <div>
  //       {item.type === 'application/pdf' && (
  //         <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
  //           onClick={() => {
  //             this.cardClose(K);
  //           }}
  //           name={item.name}
  //           size={size}
  //           icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
  //         />
  //       )}

  //       {item.type === 'image/png' && (
  //         <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
  //           onClick={() => {
  //             this.cardClose(K);
  //           }}
  //           name={item.name}
  //           size={size}
  //           icon={<Icon.Image />}
  //         />
  //       )}

  //       {item.type === 'image/jpeg' && (
  //         <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
  //           onClick={() => {
  //             this.cardClose(K);
  //           }}
  //           name={item.name}
  //           size={size}
  //           icon={<Icon.Image />}
  //         />
  //       )}

  //       {item.type === 'application/msword' && (
  //         <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
  //           onClick={() => {
  //             this.cardClose(K);
  //           }}
  //           name={item.name}
  //           size={size}
  //           icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
  //         />
  //       )}

  //       {item.type ===
  //         'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' && (
  //         <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
  //           onClick={() => {
  //             this.cardClose(K);
  //           }}
  //           name={item.name}
  //           size={size}
  //           icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
  //         />
  //       )}

  //       {item.type === 'video/mp4' && (
  //         <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
  //           onClick={() => {
  //             this.cardClose(K);
  //           }}
  //           name={item.name}
  //           size={size}
  //           icon={<Icon.Film />}
  //         />
  //       )}
  //     </div>
  //   );
  // });

  render() {
    let fileUploader = React.createRef();
    const decription = this.state.selectedFiles.map((item, key) => {
      let size = item.size / 1048576;
      size = size.toFixed(2);
      const K = item.name;
      return (
        <div>
          {item.type === 'application/pdf' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type === 'image/png' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.Image />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type === 'image/jpeg' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.Image />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type === 'application/msword' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type ===
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type === 'video/mp4' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.Film />}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="popup-box">
        <div className="box">
          <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
            {' '}
            <div className="form-close-icon">
              <Icon.X />
            </div>
            <Row className="form-row">
              <Col xs={11}>
                <h1 className="heading">Add new ticket </h1>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={1} onClick={this.props.handleClose}></Col>
            </Row>
            <FormGroup>
              <Row className="title">
                <Col xs={2} className="title-align-one">
                  <h4>Title</h4>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="title"
                    id="title"
                    value={this.state.title}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputs}
                    className="input-field"
                    placeholder="Title of the ticket"
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Row className="title">
                <Col xs={2} className="title-align-two">
                  <h4>Description</h4>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={9}>
                  <div>
                    <div className="text-box">
                      <div className="editor-wrapper">
                        <div className="editor-container">
                          <div className="text-editor">
                            <ReactQuill
                              value={this.state.editorHtml}
                              onChange={this.handleDescription}
                              placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                              modules={AddTicket.modules}
                              formats={AddTicket.formats}
                            />

                            <div className="display-cards">{decription}</div>

                            <div id="toolbar">
                              <CustomToolbar onInput={this.handleChangeFile} />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Row className="title-type">
                <Col xs={2} className="title-align-two">
                  <h4>Type </h4>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={10}>
                  <DropDown
                    onClick={this.handleType}
                    dropDwonItemArray={this.state.typeArray}
                    text={this.state.type}
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Row className="title">
                <Col xs={2} className="title-align-two">
                  <h4>Priority </h4>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={10}>
                  <DropDown
                    onClick={this.handlePriority}
                    dropDwonItemArray={this.state.priorityArray}
                    text={this.state.priority}
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Row className="title">
                <Col sm={2} className="title-align-one">
                  <h4>Assignee</h4>
                </Col>
                <Col sm={4} className="imageAssigneeCol">
                  <InputFieldWithImage
                    value={this.state.assignee}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputs}
                    picture={Amy}
                    className="field-image"
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Row className="title">
                <Col xs={2} className="title-align-one">
                  <h4 className="title-employer">Employer</h4>
                  <Label className="text-optional">Optional</Label>
                </Col>
                <Col xs={4}>
                  <Input
                    type="text"
                    name="employer"
                    id="employer"
                    value={this.state.employer}
                    onChange={this.handleChangeInputs}
                    className="input-field-employee"
                  />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Row>
                <Col xs={4} className="submit-button">
                  <ActionButton text="Send" />
                </Col>
              </Row>
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddTicket;
```

This is how i use it in the return function

```
 <div className="display-cards">{decription}</div>
```

Comment: If you remove that from render you can't access item. You are rendering the array items in a loop, unless this function is not for rendering, you can't get it out from the render

Comment: Can you post a full code? You question is unclear for me.

Comment: @ArtemMedianyk I updated the question.Full code is this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define decription before render() function as below..

```
  decription = () => (
    <>
      {


    // Start .map function

        this.state.selectedFiles.map((item, key) => {
        let size = item.size / 1048576;
        size = size.toFixed(2);
        const K = item.name;
        return (
          <div>
            {item.type === 'application/pdf' && (
              <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
                onClick={() => {
                  this.cardClose(K);
                }}
                name={item.name}
                size={size}
                icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
              />
            )}
  
            {item.type === 'image/png' && (
              <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
                onClick={() => {
                  this.cardClose(K);
                }}
                name={item.name}
                size={size}
                icon={<Icon.Image />}
              />
            )}

          {item.type === 'image/jpeg' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.Image />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type === 'application/msword' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type ===
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.FileEarmarkText />}
            />
          )}

          {item.type === 'video/mp4' && (
            <SelectedFilesDisplayLabel
              onClick={() => {
                this.cardClose(K);
              }}
              name={item.name}
              size={size}
              icon={<Icon.Film />}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      );
    })

    // End .map function


      }
    </>
  )
```

And use it in div of render()

```
<div className="display-cards">{this.decription()}</div>
```

Here, you have to know the difference between this.decription and this.decription()
Very important...